# Find a "date" from a table

Tags: calendar, tabular

I want  to create a "Table" which is like a calendar with all months and days from 1-31. But what I want to do is: If the user picks a months and a day it has to give you a number (not random) For example

```
Days | Ene | Feb | Mar
----------------------
1   | A1 | A4  | A7
---------------------
2   | A2  | A5  | A8
---------------------
3   | A3  | A6  | A9
---------------------
```

If the user write or pick Ene 1, he will get A1 or Feb 2, will get A5 (and so on). That's the questions, how can I build it? PHP? Javascript? Java? Using SQL/DataBases?

Comment: Please describe a bit more detailed what your goal is.

Comment: Thats all. It's like Excel, you use FINV and COINCIDE in same formula (jndexed) and then it gives you the result. But.. build it for mobile or web is different and I don't know how. PHP, JAVA, etc and then find in the right forum or person.

Comment: You can do this in any programming language

Comment: Ok, but... how?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
map.get( Month.FEBRUARY ).get( 2 - 1 )
```

> A5

## Java

### `Month` enum

First, you should know that Java has pre-defined a set of 12 objects for the months, in the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum. By the way, the enum facility in Java is much more powerful and flexible than is usual in most languages; you may want to [learn more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

By the way, you can ask the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) class to automatically localize the name of the month via the [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) method.

### `List`

You numbers happen to be 1, 2, 3, so we can use those to access a `List`.

Unfortunately, access into a `List` is only provided as an index, meaning 0-based counting (an unfortunate hangover from the early days of programming). So we must subtract one from the day-of-month. For example, for the 1st, use 0, for the 2nd, use 1.

### `Map`

We can map each month to its list of values using a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

### Collection literals

Java 9 brings handy new [`Map.ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)) and [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)) methods for concisely generating unmodifiable collections.

```
Map< Month, List< String > > map = 
    Map.ofEntries(
        entry( Month.JANUARY , List.of( "A1" , "A2" , "A3" ) ) ,  // This syntax requires at top:    import static java.util.Map.entry ;
        entry( Month.FEBRUARY , List.of( "A4" , "A5" , "A6" ) ) ,
        entry( Month.MARCH , List.of( "A7" , "A8" , "A9" ) )
    )
;
```

### Accessing `Map` and `List`

Try it out. Simulate the user’s input of a month and day.

```
Month m = Month.FEBRUARY;
int dayOfMonth = 2;
```

Or get the month by number, 1-12 for January-December.

```
Month m= Month.of( 2 );
```

Access our `Map` to get that month’s `List`. Passing a `Month` object gets us back the `List` object we had put into the map.

```
List< String > list = map.get( m );
```

Access that `List` to get our desired `String`, such as `A5`.

```
String result = list.get( dayOfMonth - 1 );  // Subtract one for zero-based index.
```

Or, combine those two lines into one, accessing both the `Map` and the `List`.

```
String result = map.get( m ).get( dayOfMonth - 1 ); // One-liner, alternative.
```

> A5

Let’s see all that code together.

```
Map< Month, List< String > > map = Map.ofEntries(
        entry( Month.JANUARY , List.of( "A1" , "A2" , "A3" ) ) ,  // This syntax requires at top:    import static java.util.Map.entry ;
        entry( Month.FEBRUARY , List.of( "A4" , "A5" , "A6" ) ) ,
        entry( Month.MARCH , List.of( "A7" , "A8" , "A9" ) )
);

Month m = Month.FEBRUARY;                             // Or, Month.of( 2 )
int dayOfMonth = 2;

List< String > list = map.get( m );                   // Passing a `Month` object gets us back the `List` object we had put into the map.
String result = list.get( dayOfMonth - 1 );           // Subtract one for zero-based index counting to access `List`. 

String result2 = map.get( m ).get( dayOfMonth - 1 );  // One-liner, alternative.
```